# Show data in non-adjacent columns of rdlc report

Tags: sql, rdlc

I have RDLC report which requires showing data in non-adjacent columns of a table as in the format:

```
Name  | Date | Signature | Name  | Date | Signature
```

Date and Signature are only there for persons listed to sign and put the date signed.

Sample data is coming from a Grantees table as in the ff. structure:

```
name    gender   age 
------  -------  ----    
Tres    Male     24         
Arlyn   Female   24
Coi     Male     23 
Dot     Female   22
Chong   Male     20
Baby    Female   20
Winter  Male     20
```

As **name** column is only relevant, how can I design my table to output as

```
Name      | Date    | Signature | Name       | Date    | Signature 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Tres      |         |           | Arlyn      |         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Coi       |         |           | Dot        |         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Chong     |         |           | Baby       |         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Winter    |         |           |            |         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried using table with structure above setting Fields!name.Value for 2 columns. It ends up repeating each name value in those columns.
Using matrix, I inserted a column group on name column. It is showing all the values, but only horizontally.

I assume it can be done using matrix, but I dont know how.

Comment: A basic column wise group would push those values out to the right. You have not given enough information about your data to help. Where is the relationship defined between Name as a column and Name as a row?

Comment: @Ross, I edited above for more info.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are asking now. You want to print top Left to Right, Top to bottom with two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Report's Columns property to push out your data without the need to modify your data. Other options would require that you modify the data used by your report.

This is similar to printing address labels. You can access the Columns property of the report by clicking on the report canvas, an empty region of the report. Next, navigate to the object explorer or the report properties and select the Columns property and enter the value 2. You will see a split region. The report is now configured to render the records left to right over the number of columns you have defined, in your case 2. You will need to duplicate the column headers on the newly created second column.

Comment: I have split the report body into 2 columns. But I cannot add another table or table fields into column 2...

Comment: Doh! sorry. The render process will handle the headers and data formatting. Just set column one to 50% of the width of the report and column one will be duplicated over to the other column during runtime...like a mirror but with the offset records.